# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I do not know exactly how this works, so that's why I'm asking. I'm still working on a Bulletin Board System and now I want under each **category**, a **subcategory**.

For example:
[image]

I have done this using the following thread on LaraCasts:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-getting-subcategories-from-the-categories

Now my IndexController looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Thread;
use App\Chat;
use App\Category;


class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $threads = Thread::all()->toArray();
        $chats = Chat::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(50)->with('author')->get();
        $categories = Category::with('sub_category')->get();

        return view('index', compact('threads','chats','categories'));
    }

 }
```

This is my Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{


    public function sub_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function parent_category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }


}
```

My view (index.blade.php):

```
  @foreach($categories as $category)
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  {{ $category->caption }}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">



        @foreach($category->sub_category as $sub_category)

               <div class="row forum-row">

                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-sm-8">

                     <div class="hidden-xs visible-sm visible-lg visible-md pull-left forum-icon-read">
                     <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                     </div>
                     <a href="#">{{ $sub_category->caption }}</a><br>
                     <small>{{ $sub_category->desc }}</small>

                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 forum-latest-container">
                     <p class="forum-data cutoff"><a href="#">Test</a></p>
                     <small>
                     door <a class="Donateur" href="/user-Sygun">Sygun</a>
                     <p class="forum-data">
                     2 minuten geleden </p>
                     </small>
                  </div>

               </div>
                @endforeach


            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
       @endforeach
```

I also have two database tables:

- Sub_categories (id, caption, parent_id, min_rank, desc)
- Categories (id, caption, min_rank, desc)

The error message I get:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can you tell me what is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have two tables in your DB `Sub_categories` and `Categories`?

Comment: Yes I have @AmitGupta

Comment: Is `$category->sub_category` an array? (Verify by `var_dump($category->sub_category);` before the inner loop) - perhaps you're just looking to loop `$category` instead?

Comment: Then you must have `Sub_categories` model. If yes then show it in your question. And what is the relation between both?

Comment: I don't know it's an array. You can't see that in my code? @Qirel

Comment: We can't know what the values of your objects/variables are, no (unless they are explicitly assigned).

Comment: I only have 'category' model. I think there is no need sub_category model right?

Comment: @Qirel My startpost contains all the code which has to do with the sub_categories. I have nothing more

Comment: If you don't need `sub_category` model then why do have it's table. Your relation says that you want a self-table relation between both. It means that you will save category and sub_category in the same table. Is it correct?

Comment: I follow it no more, haha. But can you give me a concrete answer how this can work? Like my photo. Main Categories are working, but the subcategories not. Can you tell me what I need to customize In my code? So, how should I do this... @AmitGupta

Comment: Will a category have multiple sub_category?

Comment: Yes, @AmitGupta

Answer (score 0):

Create two model named `Category` and  `SubCategory`.

In Category model

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory', 'parent_id');
}
```

In SubCategory model

```
public function parent_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

Then in your controller query it like:

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();
```

And hopefully your `foreach` will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error. How the database structure should be in your opinion? So how should the names of the tables and do I have to change something in the column names?

Comment: Where do I have to put that function? In which file? @AmitGupta

Comment: In your controller, after the line `$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();`.

Comment: Collection {#231 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▶]
}

Comment: Expand it and add it your question.

Answer (score 0):

Category model

`public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany('SubCategory', 'parent_id');
}`

On view

`@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory) 
      {{$subcategory->caption}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach`

And make sure you create SubCategory model.